# best way to choose the majority among three

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation

Edit: for what could be understood from explanations, answers and example:

I have three variables, each variable can assume just two specifics values. For example, this value can be 0 or 1.

I'd like a logic where the output would be the value which is present in the majority of the three variables.

For example:

> If `x=0`, `y=0` and `z=1`, the output would be 0.
>
> If `x=1`, `y=0` and `z=1`, the output would be 1.

There's an answer from @Femaref that gives a good result when the possible values are 0 and 1, but I need a generic solution, that can handle any possible values for the variables.

Comment: please rephrase question, it's difficult to interpret what you are trying to imply.

Comment: Step 1: Accept answers for some of your previous questions.

Comment: Are the only possible values of your variables 0 and 1 ?

Comment: I have a doubt you told utput: it depends by the larger of the three 
then why 
001->0 100->0 101->1

Comment: @Vivek when SecureFish says "larger" he means "more". So in the case of 001, there are more 0s, thus the output is 0.

Comment: @SecureFish are you looking for the **mode**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if x==y then return x else return z
```

This doesn't depend on the possible values being 0 and 1.

Comment: +1 :great, nothing like a logic answer...

Answer (score 14):

```
if((x+y+z) >= 2)
  return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: just interpreting the example, could be horribly wrong as he didn't tell everything.

Comment: Could make it a clean one-liner with `?:`. Nice answer.

Comment: Providing a simplistic answer to an underspecified problem is worse than no answer at all.

Comment: @Jim - the specification and answer are quite clear

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a table lookup. Convert your three bits of input into a number, and use that to index into an array holding the correct result for each possible input.

You could use simple math instead, and check for a sum >= 2, but it's hard to guess whether that's a good idea or not. It fits the requirement at hand, but it's not as open to easy modification, if that's ever likely to be needed.

Edit: The table-driven approach would look something like (syntax may be a bit off -- I've mostly done C++ lately):

```
int outputs[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};

return outputs[a<<2 | b << 1 | c];
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. A code sample would help.

Comment: Easy modification? To *not* find the majority? Would you use a table lookup in preference to a two-param function of such 0-or-1 values, just in case you want to change `and` to do something else in future? ;-)